# re.split() function throwing error for Python 3.6 version

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-3.6, python-re

I am trying to find strings of pattern (letters)(digits) and make them as (letters)-(digits).
For e.g.: If test001 is found, replace that with test-001.
So, I need to split the string at first digit following the letters.
I am using regular expressions 'match' and 'split' functions for the same.

```
if re.match(r'^\D+\d*$', str):
     parts = re.split(r'(?=\d)', str, 1)
     updated_str = parts[0] + "-" + parts[1]
```

It is working for other python versions, but failing for python 3.6 version, throwing error:
**ValueError: split() requires a non-empty pattern match.**
Can someone help me with achieving the same, which can work with all the versions of python.

Comment: Yes, because in the earlier versions it is not possible to use zero length patterns with `re.split`.  You can capture what you need in the first regex, and then access the captured groups. Or, just use `re.sub(r'^(\D+)(\d*)$', r'\1-\2', s)`, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/U1M7t5).

Answer (score 1):

Before Python 3.7, [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) did not allow to split on "a pattern that could match an empty string".

You can insert the hyphen with a single `re.sub` call:

```py
import re

s = "test001"
print(re.sub(r'^(\D+)(\d+)$', r'\1-\2', s))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/dHqixZ).

Note that `^(\D+)(\d*)$` also matches strings like `a:b`, without digits at the end, so you could end up with a `a:b-` string, that is why I used `+` after `\d`.

Note also that `\D` matches any non-digit char. If you really want to match just letters, you should use either `[a-zA-Z]` (if you only need to support ASCII letters), or `[^\W\d_]` to support any Unicode letters.

Comment: One question here, if I want to make digits to 5 digits. For ex: I want 'test-00001' for 'test-01' or 'test-001'. If it possible in the same re.sub() call or I need to do that separately?

Comment: @Pallavi You can use `re.sub(r'^(\D+)(\d+)$', lambda x: rf'{x.group(1)}-{x.group(2).zfill(5)}', s)` then (see [demo](https://ideone.com/dHqixZ)).